# Serialize object returned by a Task with unknown Type

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a List where each task can have a different return type. So I don't know in advance which class type the task returns.
The code below compiles but obiously it crashes because the serializer not only doesn't know from where to take the Type and how to serialize a generic object but also I get Exception "System.InvalidCastException" on the task boxing.
Is there a way to instruct the JavascriptSerializer to serialize against some specific class/model retrieved for example by the task.getType() method call ?

```
 public List<string> convertTasks(List<Task> taskList) 
 {
     List<string> jsonresult = new List<string>();
     foreach (Task task in taskList) {
         var result = ((Task<List<object>>)task).Result;
         foreach (var _unknownObject in result)
         {
            jsonresult.Add( new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_unknownObject));
         }
     }
     return jsonresult;
 }
```

Comment: so use some generics rather than object?

Comment: Task.getType() can be any possible type. For example Product, Category o other custom classes. I cannot just cast by a specific type.

Comment: The serializer should be fine with your code not knowing what the object type is, but there are other potential errors I can see happening here. For example, you're adding to the `result` list while you're iterating over it. What error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException

Comment: The invalid cast is almost certainly from `((Task<List<object>>)task).Result;` and has nothing to do with the serializer

Comment: That's probably because the `task.Result` is not actually a `List<object>`, right?

Comment: your (pseudocode) code is really bad written, `public function`, `result` is declared twice. `Serialize` should get `string`, right, so why you say result is dynamic?

Comment: it's a List<Product> but can also not be a list of something. can be a Product a Category. I mean a Task List with diffent types of objects

Comment: Lei Yang ..only 1 typo

Comment: Well think whatever you want I cannot paste here 2500 lines of code. I fixed anyway

Comment: Nobody's asking you to paste your 2500 lines of code. But try writing minimal code that actually compiles and runs, but which demonstrates the issue you're running into, and post that.

Comment: Because in my business logic every object should be converted to a json regardless from the type. My question was is there a way to serialize the Task whatever the input type is.

Comment: Yes, and no. The Serialize method takes any object. ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.serialize?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Script_Serialization_JavaScriptSerializer_Serialize_System_Object_)). The problem is you cant know what your task returns so you cant get it out.

Comment: Exactly i know in which range of classes the output is but don't know exactly which object. Every element of the List<Task> can have a different return Task Type

Comment: So the answer is , it cannot be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234910/discussion-between-jamiec-and-claudio-ferraro).

Answer (score 1):

The only way you will *ever* get something like this to work is type the argument as `List<Task<IEnumerable<object>>` instead of `List<Task>` - this at least indicates that the result of the task is enumerable, and that the enumerated items are some object.

I also suggest you make it `async` so you can `await` instead of using `.Result`

```
public async Task<List<string>> convertTasks(List<Task<IEnumerable<object>>> taskList) 
 {
     List<string> jsonresult = new List<string>();
     foreach (var task in taskList) 
     {
         var result = await task;
         foreach (var _unknownObject in result)
         {
            jsonresult.Add( new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_unknownObject));
         }
     }
     return jsonresult;
 }
```

A somewhat mockup of this situation is shown here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/747B65

Your assumption that the serializer cannot deal with any object is incorrect. It can.